# Cant find the Source Code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have a .Net Project which is a webService with Soap / RestApi which i worked on a few years ago in Visual Studio 2017. Since then i upgraded my PC and now i am having hard time finding the actual source code of the project. I have compressed backups of my old system which doesn't allow for searching on file names so i am wondering if there is a way based on the compiled code to either get the Location of the source where it was compiled from or if there is a way to get a list from the old Visual Studio what the most recent projects where and where they are stored. I know this is a long shot but i don't want to restore a full backup nor do i want to use the recompiler to recreate the project. Hope someone can share some wisdom with me

Comment: You have to have the original symbol files (.pdb) which contains the source file paths. But learn a source control system like Git please, or next time you are going to lose the code again.

Comment: I have the pdb file, how do you open it since it seems to be compiled. And i am with you on Git, i am using Git on all my PHP and NodeJs stuff but didn't do it for .Net since i keep copys of project on a dropbox share but in this case its seems to be only compiled version